# Inner shadow on circle Android Canvas

Tags: android-layout, draw, android

I need to make  inner shadow and gradient on Circle which I draw in onDraw() method of my view  see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kuVJ.jpg) (sorry, because of I'm new to StackOverflow I can't post images yet)

I figure out how to get gradient working but I can't get inner shadow done
All I've found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469748/imageview-with-rounded-corners-and-inner-shadow) post, but it seems a bit complicated and not exactly what I need

I've tried using setShadowLayer(), but it I probably can't get it working right, because besides inner shadow, I get outer shadow too, and this is not what I need

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able the avoid the outer shadow by setting the clip to the circle as that will restrict the drawing just to inside the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw 2 circles(one of them smaller then the other) both with LinearGradient

The outer circle will have LinearGradient with "darker" color, and the smaller circle also will have LinearGradient but with "lighter" color. both circles share the SAME origin which will produce what you expected(its like a shadow ring)

hops it help