# Bitmap image with rounded corners and inner shadow

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, draw

I'm basically doing, is drawing a black rounded rectangle first and then drawing a rounded-corners bitmap with fading edges (with the BlurMaskFilter) on top of it. The result is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469748/imageview-with-rounded-corners-and-inner-shadow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageView with rounded corners and inner shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469748/imageview-with-rounded-corners-and-inner-shadow)